# 1.0TB DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON, Total Powered On Time 1 Month?

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, disk

I bought this PC about 2-3 months ago. I dual booted Ubuntu and Windows but then decided to delete windows entirely and use it as a storage partition. I was going to delete everything and switch to a debian based OS, but it had showed me in the disks utility that the "DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON" I don't understand how this is possible with a total Powered On time of 1 month.
[Smart Scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7oUv.png)

more info:
HDD: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100 (AX1R4C)
Is there a possibility this can be reading something wrong, or is there anyway to fix this? (im guessing not from the other posts i saw.)

Comment: If a drive is failing you should see the number increase, is the number higher now than the number in the screenshot? If so it's likely a bad apple

Comment: The number of sectors I mean

Comment: My perception is that Toshiba hard drives have a high failure rate... so it's certainly possible for your to fail after 1 month. There may still be a warranty on it though.

Comment: This is a hardware question which is off topic here but fine over on [SU]. You should take that warning at face value. A large share (~10 % if I recall correctly) of hard drives fail during the first 3 months of their productive life. In the best case the readings coming from the drive are wrong which means you won't know when the drive is *actually* about to fail. Having a drive fail without a notice period for a replacement and/or back-up is not worth the hassle. If the drive is new it's very likely under warranty and the seller will exchange it for free.

Comment: How does it detect that the "DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON"? Does it do some measure of performance and (based on that) predict imminent failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the help, but the thing ended up failing anyway. I just bought another one on Amazon. I can say this is unsolved and maybe its nothing to do with Ubuntu, just a faulty/cheap hdd. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

I recommend testing it with `smartctl` to be sure.

1. Open a terminal window
2. Run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install smartmontools
   ```
3. Then you'll want to run:

   ```
   sudo smartctl -x /dev/sdY #Replace "Y" appropriately for your system
   ```

If `smartctl` also indicates a failure, then I would immediately backup any data on the disk and contact HP for a warranty HDD replacement.

Comment: how will i know if it has error, there is a lot of stuff

Comment: For the price, get a new HDD, if you can afford it you can get 1tb ssd for 200 on eBay used. I've had new disks fail smart check immediately after purchase and thankfully returned them immediately.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for new(er) drives to fail prematurely. I have had brand new drives fail within 3 months. You could

```
fsck -r
```

To check and attempt a repair on the disk. However I would not recommend relying on a drive that has been tagged for failure. Backup any data that is on the drive and get a replacement. Better safe than sorry. You don't want to load it with data and then have it actually fail.

Comment: that returns `fsck from util-linux 2.29`. also do you know if this is covered by warranty for HP?

Comment: I'm sorry I should of been more in depth. You have to tell fsck what to check. So fsck -r /dev/sda for example. There are many ways to list the current drives. sudo fdisk -l or df -h   . If it is the only drive or drive with the operating system you will have to run Ubuntu from a live cd to check it. You would have to check hp warranty I'm not sure how they handle it. If the computer is only a month old I can't see why it wouldn't be. Check their warranty though it may not cover altering the OS that was preinstalled.